# How to create a regression function that predicts X values based on Asymptotic Regression using SciPy-optimize?

Tags: python, regression, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, asymptote

I have a dataset consisting of two columns X and Y.

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2207 |
| 2 | 2407 |
| 5 | 2570 |
| 7 | 2621 |
| 10 | 2723 |
| 20 | 2847 |
| 30 | 2909 |
| 40 | 2939 |
| 50 | 2963 |

This is a dataset:

[image]

The values in the second column Y are certain figures estimated from column X.
The problem comes back when I have to predict a new value not present in the column Y and that consequently I go back to the corresponding value in column X. To find the values within the range of the column Y written above I use interpolation.
I need that the regression function allow me to predict all the values I want which are greater than the values in column Y.
For now I have used a software (MyCurveFit) which gives me the values of the columns X and Y,creating a graph and a function.

this is a certain graph from my dataset value:

[image]

The most similar function I think is Asymptotic Regression but I don't know how to develop it.
These are the calculations that this software does:

[image]

So, I'd like to know what the equation was that, if you put a new value in the Y column, allow me to continue the line obtained by Asymptotic Regression and consequently predicting the X result.

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| ? | 2980 |
| ? | 2995 |
| ? | 2999 |
| ? | 3005 |

As a programming language I'm using Python.

Comment: Invert your fit function (solve for x).

Comment: Don't paste images for parameter values; paste text.

Comment: @Binod Comini my answer wasn't satisfying your question?

Answer (score 0):

Invert the function:

```py
import numpy as np

a = -0.007823866
b = 0.2984279
c = 0.1652267
d = 3512.422

def forward(x):
    return d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)**b)

def inverse(y):
    return c*((y - a)/(d - y))**(1/b)

x = np.array((0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
y = np.array((0, 2207, 2407, 2570, 2621, 2723, 2847, 2909, 2939, 2963))
print('y approx:')
print(forward(x))
print('x approx:')
print(inverse(y))
```

```
y approx:
[-7.82386600e-03  2.21698252e+03  2.38108163e+03  2.57989010e+03
  2.64703036e+03  2.71456236e+03  2.83489343e+03  2.89861616e+03
  2.94089737e+03  2.97205243e+03]
x approx:
[1.89762934e-20 9.59977992e-01 2.24136479e+00 4.76461272e+00
 6.13180316e+00 1.04710052e+01 2.15511573e+01 3.21480702e+01
 3.94727621e+01 4.68115981e+01]
```

Comment: Good catch but OP asked for using SciPy-optimize maybe

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Thanks to @Reinderien solution I could reflect what you want as follows:

```py
# reproduce data in dataframe using pandas
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Give string data
data_string = """|X|Y|
|    0    |    0    |
|    1    |   2207  |
|    2    |   2407  |
|    5    |   2570  |
|    7    |   2621  |
|   10    |   2723  |
|   20    |   2847  |
|   30    |   2909  |
|   40    |   2939  |
|   50    |   2963  |"""

# Remove the extra spaces
data_string = data_string.replace(' ', '')

# Read the string into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_string), sep='|', engine='python')

# Remove empty columns and rows
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').dropna(axis=0, how='all')

# Remove leading/trailing whitespaces in column names
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

# Reset index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
#print(df)

# Create regression formula based on @Reinderien
import numpy as np

a = -0.007823866
b = 0.2984279
c = 0.1652267
d = 3512.422

def forward(x):
    return d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)**b)

def inverse(y):
    return c*((y - a)/(d - y))**(1/b)

# find Y value for 50 using formula
d_new = np.array((50))
dd_new = forward(d_new) 
print('Exact Y for x=50:')
print(dd_new)

#Excat Y for x=50:
#2972.052430476231


y_new = np.array((2972, 2980, 2995, 2999, 3005))
x_new = inverse(y_new) 
print('New x approx:')
print(x_new)
#New x approx:
#[49.98079241 53.01746832 59.33542751 61.17166248 64.05688327]

#df=df.astype(float)
df.X = pd.to_numeric(df.X)
df.Y = pd.to_numeric(df.Y)

#visulize the regression data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import seaborn as sns  
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

ax = df.plot.line(x='X', y='Y', marker="o", ms=5 , label=' Y', c='b')
plt.plot(x_new, y_new, marker="^", ms=5 ,label=' Predicted X', linestyle='--', c='orange')
plt.xlim(-5, 65)
plt.ylim(-1000, 4000)
#plt.yscale('log',base=1000) 
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize=15)

ax.annotate(f'{x_new[1]:.2f}', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(x_new[1] -1 , y_new[1] +100), rotation=45)
ax.annotate(f'{x_new[2]:.2f}', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(x_new[2] -2 , y_new[2] +100), rotation=45)
ax.annotate(f'{x_new[3]:.2f}', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(x_new[3] -1 , y_new[3] +100), rotation=45)
ax.annotate(f'{x_new[4]:.2f}', xy=(x_new[4], y_new[4]-50), xytext=(x_new[4] -5 , y_new[4] -900), rotation=45, bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="y"), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.2"))

formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True) 
formatter.set_powerlimits((-1,1)) 
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter) 
plt.title('Predicted/retrieving X based on inverted of (regression) function')
plt.legend(loc = "upper left")
plt.show()
```

Note: Alternatively, you can also use [pynverse](https://pypi.org/project/pynverse/) for *calculating the numerical inverse of any invertible continuous function*.

---

[image: img]

Basically, you just need to find the inversion of (regression function) formula that describes your model to find new Xs according to new given Ys. You don't need to fit a curve over your data necessarily.

Short note: I noticed that the data you have shown in pic for X-axis and Y-axis are not perfectly aligned when I put them in function:

```py
# define the function
a = -0.007823866
b = 0.2984279
c = 0.1652267
d = 3512.422

def function(x, a, b, c, d):
    return d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)**b)

import math
print(f'f(0)= {math.ceil(function(0,a,b,c,d))}') #f(0)= 0
print(f'f(1)= {function(1,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )       #f(1)= 2217.0
print(f'f(2)= {function(2,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )       #f(2)= 2381.1
print(f'f(5)= {function(5,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )       #f(5)= 2579.9
print(f'f(7)= {function(7,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )       #f(7)= 2647.0
print(f'f(10)={function(10,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )      #f(10)=2714.6
print(f'f(20)={function(20,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )      #f(20)=2834.9
print(f'f(30)={function(30,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )      #f(30)=2898.6
print(f'f(40)={function(40,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )      #f(40)=2940.9
print(f'f(50)={function(50,a,b,c,d):.1f}' )      #f(50)=2972.1
```

- Fitting curve using [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) package:

```py
# fit a second degree polynomial to the data
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# define the function
a = -0.007823866
b = 0.2984279
c = 0.1652267
d = 3512.422

def function(x, a, b, c, d):
    return d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)**b)


# choose the input and output variables
x_data, y_data = np.array(df.X), np.array(df.Y)
print(x_data)
print(y_data)


p0 = [a, b, c, d]

# perform the curve fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(function, x_data, y_data , p0=p0)
#popt, _ = curve_fit(forward, x, y)

# summarize the parameter values
print(popt)

## plot the results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns  
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

#plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, marker="o", ms=8 , label="Data"                  , c='b')
plt.plot(x_new, y_new,   marker="o", ms=8 , label='New Ys', linestyle='--', c='darkblue')
plt.plot(x_data, function(x_data, *popt),  linestyle=':', c='orange', marker="s", ms=5, label="Fitted Curve")
#just for show case once if we could extend our fit cure over new data
plt.plot(inverse(y_new),  y_new,  linestyle=':', c='orange', marker="^", ms=5, label="Fitted Curve over new Ys")

plt.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
plt.xlim(-5, 65)
plt.ylim(-1000, 4000)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize=15)

plt.annotate(f'{x_new[1]:.2f}', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(x_new[1] -1 , y_new[1] +100), rotation=45)
plt.annotate(f'{x_new[2]:.2f}', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(x_new[2] -2 , y_new[2] +100), rotation=45)
plt.annotate(f'{x_new[3]:.2f}', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(x_new[3] -1 , y_new[3] +100), rotation=45)
plt.annotate(f'{x_new[4]:.2f}', xy=(x_new[4], y_new[4]-50), xytext=(x_new[4] -5 , y_new[4] -900), rotation=45, bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="y"), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.2"))


plt.title('Curve-Fitting with SciPy-optimize')
plt.legend(loc = "best")
plt.show()
```

---

[image: img]

here my observation shows that when you set `p0` within `curve_fit()` it perfectly fit over data.

According to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

- Fitting curve using [lmfit](/questions/tagged/lmfit) package check its [docs](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/):

```py
#!pip install lmfit
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model

a = -0.007823866
b = 0.2984279
c = 0.1652267
d = 3512.422

def forward(x):
    return d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)**b)

# create model from your model function
mymodel = Model(forward)

# create initial set of named parameters from argument of your function
params = mymodel.make_params(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)

# choose the input and output variables
x_data, y_data = df.X, df.Y

# run fit, get result
result = mymodel.fit(y_data, params, x=x_data)

# print out full fit report: fit statistics, best-fit values, uncertainties
#print(result.fit_report())  #error: ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence 

# make a stacked plot of residual and data + fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns  
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

plt.figure()
result.plot()
plt.xlim(-5, 65)
plt.ylim(-1000, 4000)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize=15)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))

plt.title('Curve-Fitting with LMfit Model')
plt.legend(loc = "best")
plt.show()
```

---

[image: img]